# 'protoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, protocol-buffers

When I tried this for **Protobuf Compilation** by cmd

`protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

It shows me

`'protoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

**How to fix this ??**

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you had the same problem I had.
Are you following the [TensorFlow 2 Object Detection API tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#id5)?

At some point you go to the [protoc release pages](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases) and see downloads such as
"protobuf-all-3.17.0.zip" and "protoc-3.17.0-win64.zip" (BIG difference). Make sure you download "protoc" and not "protobuf-all".

Make sure you can find "protoc.exe" in the folder you extract. Example, in my computer I have:

---

C:\Program Files\Google Protobuf\bin\protoc.exe

---

"protoc.exe" is the compiler.

If anyone reading this is totally lost, see if you can find your c++ compiler.
For me it is

---

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe

---

and the compiler is called "cl.exe"